# How to know if an AWS Web ACL is actually being used

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-waf

I have 1 Web ACL in AWS account that I want to delete.

```
(list-acls output) 
WEBACLS foo1acl abcd123-ghij-klmnop


(get-acls output)
{
    "WebACL": {
        "WebACLId": "abcd123-ghij-klmnop", 
        "Rules": [
            {
                "Priority": 1, 
                "Action": {
                    "Type": "ALLOW"
                }, 
                "Type": "REGULAR", 
                "RuleId": "abcd1234-5678-9123-b53e-abcdefghj78"
            }
        ], 
        "DefaultAction": {
            "Type": "BLOCK"
        }, 
        "Name": "foo", 
        "WebACLArn": "arn:aws:waf::foo", 
        "MetricName": "foo"
    }
}
```

How can I tell if this Web ACL is actually used or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web ACL is associated with a resource, it is being used. To check this either go to the console or use this API to see if it's associated: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/wafv2/list-resources-for-web-acl.html